raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e distutils.errors.DistutilsError
I've made a recommendation system using python 3.9.2 using surprise library. Then my employer asked if i could make a website demonstrating the recommendation system. So I made one using flask. The problem is when I wanted to deploy the python 3.9 flask app on apache server it gave me 7024 error - incorrect function. But when I followed the same steps using python 3.12 it worked just fine and the app ran. However, the recommendation function throws an error as the surprise library is not installed. When I try to install it, the following error occurrs.

Collecting surprise
  Using cached surprise-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (327 bytes)
Collecting scikit-surprise (from surprise)
  Using cached scikit-surprise-1.1.3.tar.gz (771 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      <string>:65: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************    
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************    
      
      !!
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      D:\flaskApp\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 101, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
          subprocess.check_call(cmd)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\flaskApp\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpx2euatq3', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.17.3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
     
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\flaskApp\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\flaskApp\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\flaskApp\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup 
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup 
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 65, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 640, in fetch_build_eggs          return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 798, in resolve  
          dist = self._resolve_dist(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 834, in _resolve_dist
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1104, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1115, in obtain  
          return installer(requirement) if installer else None
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kkvji2sx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 103, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
          raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
      distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['D:\\flaskApp\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpx2euatq3', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.17.3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip`






I have tried reinstalling python3.12 and updating pip. I also tried to search what is the building wheels but couldn't find out what  the problem is. Regarding python 3.9 I have searched forever to identify the problem with apache on my local computer but did also not find any solution.

You would be surprised to know that surprise is still not supported for Python 3.12
Please Downgrade your python version to 3.11 or less to work with surprise.
https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/issues/473
